# createLinearGradient without color blending

Tags: javascript, canvas

With the `createLinearGradient` we can create color gradient and colors blend as per the stop value in `addColorStop`.

```
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'blue');   
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'red');
```

Can we avoid color blending and have different colors as per the stop value without Blending or Gradient. Maybe this is not possible with `createLinearGradient` any other API?

I know we can create this using two different `fillRect` and `fillStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you mean, but if you want a clear stop from two different colors, you can simply set both colors at the same stop position:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,150);
// implicit from -Infinity "green"
grad.addColorStop(0.33, "green");
grad.addColorStop(0.33, "yellow"); // same stop as previous color
grad.addColorStop(0.66, "yellow");
grad.addColorStop(0.66, "red");    // same stop as previous color
// implicit to +Infinity "red"
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks..it is hard to understand the API `addColorStop` as per the document `A value between 0.0 and 1.0 that represents the position between start and end in a gradient`. But if I reduce the size of the actula rect to 10px `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 10);` then I see only green color and no yellow and read. I did try multiple combinations but not able to get the three colors fit inside the 10 px height of rectangle.

Comment: The gradient itself is Infinitely large, but you define the area of stop offset by using `createGradient(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. So `0`will be at x1, y1 and `1` will be at x2, y2.

Comment: Ok, but if I reduce the size of the actual rect to 10 px  `createGradient(0, 0, 0, 10)` that mean gradient should also fit in that range but gradient behaves in an unknown way.

Comment: `createGradient(0, 0, 300, 10)` will make your gradient go oblique from top left corner to bottom right corner of a 300x10 rectangle. If you want a vertical gradient of 10px the correct values are `createLinearGradient(0,0, 0,10)`

Comment: Yes you are right it should be `0, 0, 0, 10` and I had it for `createGradient` and also `fillRect` But not sure what should be the stop values for the `addColorStop`. I tried different combinations but I only see one color.

Comment: Always a value between 0 and 1. https://jsfiddle.net/ry3amk1t/

Comment: I did try exactly the same but in my case, it did not work. Thanks.